# How to pass state or props in react hookrouter while navigate from one page to another page

Tags: reactjs, navigation, hookrouter

I have tried `useRoutes` from `hookrouter` navigating from one page to another page which is working fine. And I want to pass some objects with that route. How should I pass an object? I have read `hookrouter` GitHub page, still I didn't get it. I tried like `navigate("/home",true,{name:"batman"});`, it doesn't help. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution for react-router-dom

If you use button as route event trigger:

```
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

<Button
  ...
  component={Link}
  to={{
    pathname: `yourRoutePath`,
    // write your custom state below
    state: {
      otherCustomState: value,
      // sample below
      prevPath: history.location.pathname,
    }
  }}
>
  next page
</Button>
```

Usage

```js
history.location.state.yourCustomState
```

Update:

#### Solution for hookrouter

Pass URL parameters: Refer to article [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-react-hooks-can-replace-react-router/), not sure whether it fits your demand

```js
const routes = {
  '/user/:id': ({id}) => <User userId={id} />
}
```

Pass implicit props: Refer to document of [passing-additional-data-to-route-functions](https://github.com/Paratron/hookrouter/blob/master/src-docs/pages/en/02_routing.md#passing-additional-data-to-route-functions)

```js
const routes = {
    '/' => () => (product) => <GeneralInfo product={product} />,
    '/details': () => (product) => <Techdetails product={product} />,
    '/buy': () => (product) => <BuyOptions product={product} />
    '/buy/:variant': ({variant}) => (product) => <Buy product={product} variant={variant} />
};

const ProductPage = ({id}) => {
    const [productObj, status] = useProduct(id);
    const match = useRoutes(routes);

    if(!match){
        return 'Page not found';
    }

    if(status.loading){
        return 'Loading product...';
    }

    return match(productObj);
};
```

Comment: This is fine will work but I wanted to know this using hookrouter, how this will work in hookrouter, passing state

Comment: @DineshKumar updated, kindly check it would be appreciated.

Comment: thankyou @kaikai, sorry for the late response, I got this but I don't want to pass data in URL, this one seems passing data through URL, u know right in react-router, we can send data to URL or we can pass store data in a state in the router params, like that I m asking sending one object

Answer (score -1):

You can use the link component in react-router-dom.

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

<Link to={`home/${obj.name}`}> Click here </Link>
```

Comment: But this is using react-router-dom, right? but I want with hookrouter any possibilities with hookrouter, I m learning hookrouter to navigate